# html - adding a div separator between 2 content divs

Tags: css, html

I am trying to put a (horizontal) separator div between my 2 content divs. Instead of putting it between them, it shows under my banner div (above the 2 content divs).

Here is structure of my html:

```
 <body>

 <div id="page">

<div id="header">

    <div id="logo"></div>

</div>

    <div id="menuContainer">

        <div id="menu">
            <ul id="btns">
                <li><a href="#">DOMOV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SVETEĽNÉ ZDROJE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CHLADIČE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NAPÁJANIE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONEKTORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OPTIKA/REFLEKTORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKTY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="separator"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">

    <div id="contentBlock">

        <div id="contentLeft">
        <p id ="nadpis">LED SVETELNE ZDROJE</p>
        <p id ="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar vitae mauris eget vehicula. Integer a mi ut lorem facilisis semper. Etiam faucibus lorem at tellus aliquam, sed aliquet risus venenatis. Etiam vulputate, magna rutrum eleifend rhoncus, justo nulla tristique magna, et tincidunt enim lacus in magna. Curabitur odio risus, eleifend vitae facilisis id, dignissim sed nunc. Pellentesque volutpat metus et scelerisque sagittis. Praesent mattis pulvinar est nec viverra. Nunc suscipit molestie fringilla.</p>
        <p id ="katalog">KATALÓG NA STAHNUTIE</p>
        <a href="#"><div id="pdf" ></div></a>

        <div id="dodavatelia">
            <div id="pic1"></div>
            <div id="pic2"></div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="contentRight">
        <p id ="rozdelenie">ZÁKLADNÉ ROZDELENIE</p>

        <ul id="rozdel">
                <li>COB</li>
                <li>SMD</li>
                <li>LED PÁSY</li>
                <li>LED MODULY</li>
            </ul>

    </div>

</div>  

<div id="oddelovac1"></div>

<div id="contentBlock">

        <div id="contentLeft">
        <p id ="nadpis">LED SVETELNE ZDROJE</p>
        <p id ="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar vitae mauris eget vehicula. Integer a mi ut lorem facilisis semper. Etiam faucibus lorem at tellus aliquam, sed aliquet risus venenatis. Etiam vulputate, magna rutrum eleifend rhoncus, justo nulla tristique magna, et tincidunt enim lacus in magna. Curabitur odio risus, eleifend vitae facilisis id, dignissim sed nunc. Pellentesque volutpat metus et scelerisque sagittis. Praesent mattis pulvinar est nec viverra. Nunc suscipit molestie fringilla.</p>
        <p id ="katalog">KATALÓG NA STAHNUTIE</p>
        <a href="#"><div id="pdf" ></div></a>

        <div id="dodavatelia">
            <div id="citizen"></div>
            <div id="qlt"></div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="contentRight">
        <p id ="rozdelenie">ZÁKLADNÉ ROZDELENIE</p>

        <ul id="rozdel">
                <li>COB</li>
                <li>SMD</li>
                <li>LED PÁSY</li>
                <li>LED MODULY</li>
            </ul>

    </div>

</div>  

 <div id="separator"></div>

 <div id="contentBlock>
 ... The same structure
 </div>

 </div>

 </div>

 </body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
 body {
 margin:0;
 }


 #page {
 width:100%;
 }

 #header{
 width:1000px;
 height:100px;
 margin:auto;
 }

 #logo {
 width:140px;
 height:47px;
 background:url('../img/logo.png')no-repeat;
 margin-top:50px;

 }

 #menuContainer { 
 height:37px;
 width:100%;
 background:#c4c8ca;
 }

 #menu{
 width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
 }

 #menu ul {
 padding-top:8px;
 text-align:right;
 }


 #banner {
 width:100%;
 height:353px;
 background:url('../img/banner.png')no-repeat;
 margin-top:2px;
 }

 #separator {
 width:100%;
 height:31px;
 background:url('../img/oddelovac.png')no-repeat;
 margin-top:6px;
 }


 #contentContainer {
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 }

 #contentBlock {
 width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
 }

 #contentLeft {
 width:650px;
 float:left;
 }

 #contentRight{
 width:350px;
 float:left;
 }
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6d7y8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `clear: both` to `#separator` or `overflow: hidden` to `#contentBlock`.

edit:

You use same `id` attribute value for many elements - there can be only one, unique.
If you want to use same style to many elements then use `class`.

Answer (score 0):

just add float:left

```
#contentBlock {
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
}

#separator {
width:100%;
height:31px;
background-color:rgb(255,0,255);
margin-top:6px;
float:left;
}
```